# jQuery continuous mousedown

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code snippets

```
$(document).mousedown(function(event) {
    doSomething();
}
```

I can capture the `mousedown` event successfully.

I am trying to do the following:

1. Capture the first `mousedown` event
2. I want to detect if the user is still holding the mouse down so I can do something else.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Something like

```
var mouseStillDown = false;

$(document).mousedown(function(event) {
    mouseStillDown = true;
    doSomething();
});

function doSomething() {
    if (!mouseStillDown) { return; } // we could have come back from
                                     // SetInterval and the mouse is no longer down
    // do something

    if (mouseStillDown) { setInterval("doSomething", 100); }
}

$(document).mouseup(function(event) {
    mouseStillDown = false;
});
```

Comment: better yet: setInterval("doSomething()",100);

And you should store a reference to the interval and then clear it (if required) before calling setInterval again, otherwise you might end up with multiple intervals running simultaneously.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, above code will generate many simultaneous intervals running at the same time, constantly creating yet more, which is really terrible.  Correct solution with single interval which is then cleared is here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8010163/2855804

Answer (score 23):

```
var int00; // declared here to make it visible to clearInterval.

$('#trigger').mousedown(function(){
    int00 = setInterval(function() { repeatingfunction(); }, 50);
}).mouseup(function() {
    clearInterval(int00);
});

function repeatingfunction() {
    // This will repeat //
}
```

You can also put a `clearInterval` on the `mouseleave` event.

Comment: Elegant solution, but a small typo .. setInterval :)

Comment: And an even smaller typo by the editor: its var int00; not var int100;

Answer (score 5):

You'd implement some recursion!

```
var mouseisdown = false;

$(document).mousedown(function(event) {
    mouseisdown = true;
    doSomething();
}).mouseup(function(event) {
    mouseisdown = false;
});

function doSomething(){
    //Code goes here
    if (mouseisdown)
        doSomething();
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work, at least on my environment. The recursive call prevents the mouseup event to fire and therefore `mouseisdown` is always true, entirely blocking the UI. It works if the recursive call is placed within a `setTimeout` function, but then I can't see the benefit of using this solution instead of the one provided by Janos.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to do something like on `mouseDown`, start doing something and continue doing it till `mouseUp` event is fired.

Comment: How can I continue doing it? Using setInterval()? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

use the mousedown event to set a flag, and mouseup to unset the flag.  Then you can simply check the flag, to see if it is set.

exmaple

```
var mouseDownFlag = false;
$(document).mousedown(function(event) {
     mouseDownFlag = true;
     someFunc();
}
$(document).mouseup(function(event) {
     mouseUpFlag = true;
}
var someFunc = function(){
     if(mouseDownFLag){//only run this function when the mouse is clicked
     // your code
         setTimeout("somefunc()", 1000); //run this function once per second if your mouse is down.
     }
}
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  var mouseStillDown = false;

  $('#some_element').mousedown(function() {
    do_something();
  }).mouseup(function() {
    clearInterval(mouseStillDown);
    mouseStillDown = false;
  });

  function do_something() {

    // add some code here that repeats while mouse down

    if (!mouseStillDown) {
      mouseStillDown = setInterval(do_something, 100);
    }

  }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let target = document.querySelector(".targetElement");
target.addEventListener('mousedown', event => {
    target.addEventListener('mousemove',doStuff);
});
target.addEventListener('mouseup', event => {
    target.removeEventListener('mousemove',doStuff);
});
function doStuff(event){
    // code
}
```

I found this much more convenient.