# jQuery get all x and y between mousedown and mouseup

Tags: javascript, jquery, raphael, mouseevent

Im using Raphael to make a simple drawing app. I trying to draw squiggly lines(is there a better word for this) at the moment, so I want to capture all the x's and y's between mousedown and mouseup. At this stackoverflow question [jQuery continuous mousedown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4961072/jquery-continuous-mousedown) there is a solution for doing something inbetween the events, but I can't get the x and y to work correctly. I'm trying to use mousemove() to get it, but mousemove() doesn't stop when the function ends. And having the function that get's the x and y call its self gets me an infinite loop. So... two things, how to continuously get the x and y's and how to avoid the infinite loop. I know how to put it into an array and make a squiggly line after, just not how to do the mouse listener. The code I have now is:

```
var paper = new Raphael($('#canvas')[0], 500, 500);
var canvas =$('#canvas');

var stillDown = false;
canvas.mousedown(function(){
    console.log("down");
    stillDown = true;
    whileDown();
});

function whileDown(){
    if(!stillDown){return;}else{
    console.log("Still in down.");
        canvas.mousemove(function(e){
        //console.log("X: " + e.offsetX + " Y: " + e.offsetY);
    });
    whileDown();
    }
}

canvas.mouseup(function(){
    stillDown = false;
});
```

My current goal is just to have it display that it's down, all the x and y's while down, and that it's up, and nothing after that, in the console. Then I'll process that info. Anyways, any help would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On mousedown, just set the boolean flag:

```
var stillDown = false;
canvas.mousedown(function(){
    console.log("down");
    stillDown = true;
});
```

On mousemove, push the coordinates to an array if the flag is set:

```
var coords = [];
canvas.mousemove(function(e){
    if(!stillDown) return;
    console.log("moving");
    coords.push({x: e.offsetX, y: e.offsetY});
    // and/or do whatever you need with the coordinates  
}
```

On mouseup, unset the flag:

```
canvas.mouseup(function(){
    stillDown = false;
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! And the reason while it doesn't get stuck in the mousemove is cause of the return when it finishes. But, What exactly was wrong with the other function?

Comment: Yes, it just aborts the mousemove stuff if the flag is not set (there are also other ways to do that, maybe more efficient, but that works). The other function had two serious issues: it called itself (into an infinite recursion, never giving a chance for the flag to clear); and it tried to set a new mousemove listener recursively too, and on every mouse down. So your code was basically trying to create *multiple* infinite loops, which is not even possible because the browser is too busy with a single one.

Comment: Ouch. Okay. That makes sense when I look at it with that explanation. Thanks a lot.