# Moving a DIV repeatedly by clicking and holding down the mouse button

Tags: jquery

I'd like move a DIV 1px each time I click an arrow icon.  No problem there.  But now I'd like to have the DIV continue to move left 1px every 100ms when I click the arrow icon and *hold* the mouse button down. Is there a standard way in jQuery to do this?

Thanks

Comment: What other research have you done on the subject? What does the jQuery `.mousedown()` method say about this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery continuous mousedown](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4961072/jquery-continuous-mousedown)

Comment: @DevlshOne  jQuery .mousedown() doesn't say anything about holding down the button. You click the button, you get the interrupt.  Period.

Comment: EXACTLY my point as you can see by the answer that was posted. Note that mine was a comment, not an answer. We try to encourage people to do a little work on their own and not rely on everything being handed to them on a silver platter.

Comment: @DevlshOne You're not making sense.  The best use of my time is to solve my problem as quickly as possible and move on to the next phase of my project.  If the problem looks like it would take me a half day to resolve, with a good chance I'll have to revisit the solution several times later to nail down corner cases,  but someone here can point me immediately to a worked-out solution that 
already has 10 upvotes,   I'll come here every time and start with that solution.  "On the shoulders of giants . . ."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to do it repeatedly yourself with a setInterval until you catch the mouseup event. If you want some code, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4961072/jquery-continuous-mousedown)

Comment: Finally, a civil answer.  Thanks.