# Continue function until mouse is released

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to be able to run the below function continuously while the mouse is down. At the moment the function excecutes once per click. I want to be able to continue running the function while mousedown and stop when the mouse is released.

```
    $('#md').mousedown(function(e){
         var pCords = e.pageY +e.pageY;
         var max = $(document).height()+$(document).width();
             var dg = 2*( pCords / max );
         $('#div').css({ 'transform':'rotate('+dg+'deg) '});
    });
```

Comment: Question is asked not properly and it issues lots of irrelevant answers. You DO NOT want this function to run continuously, because the `e.pageX` and `e.pageY` will be the same. What you need is set the flags as mentioned in more than already six answers below and have a handler `$('#md').mousemove()` where you will 1) check the flag set in mouseup/down event 2) have new coordinates of the mouse pointer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy way to do with time delay between execution of event handler:

```
var timerId = 0;

$('#md').mousedown(function(e){
             timerId = setInterval(function() {
                         var pCords = e.pageY +e.pageY;
                         var max = $(document).height()+$(document).width();
                         var dg = 2*( pCords / max );
                         $('#div').css({ 'transform':'rotate('+dg+'deg) '});
                 }, 20); // specify the required time delay here
            });

 $('#md').mouseup(function(e){
        clearInterval(timerId);
    });
```

Comment: You definitely don't want the while loop in that first chunk of code

Answer (score 1):

This issue has been addressed in: [jQuery continuous mousedown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4961072/jquery-continuous-mousedown)

It will involve setting up a flag that you can set to true when the first mousedown event occurs, and calling a function that only finishes once the flag is set back to false when the mouseup event occurs.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using a simple semaphore. Here's an example:

```
var lock = true;

$('#md').mousedown(function() {
    lock = false;

    setTimeout(function() {
        while(!lock) {
            // Do your stuff here
        }
    }, 0);
});

$(document).mouseup(function() {
    lock = true;
});
```

I hope this does the trick.
The setTimeout function detaches the execution of the function and creates an asynchronous process - this makes your code non-blocking.

I'm sure there are more sophisticated ways to solve this problem. It's just that I haven't had my coffee yet. :)

Answer (score 0):

like this? making a global boolean variable to track if mouse is up, then looping your function while mouse is down on that element.

```
 var ismouseup = false;

 $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#md').mousedown(function(e){
         ismouseup = false;
         while(!ismouseup)
        {
            //do your thing
        }
    });

    $('#md').mouseup(function(e){
        ismouseup = true;
    }
});
```

--edit: set ismouseup to true when mouseup. sorry.

Comment: You have an infinite loop here. You never set isMouseUp to true. Ever.

Comment: This technique won't work because the `while` loop blocks execution, so the mouseup handler will never get called.

Comment: ah. then settimeout will do the trick then? settimeout will remove while loop's execution block?

Answer (score 0):

You can use setTimeout. This will run every 1 sec when mousedown

```
 $('#md').on({
        mousedown: function () {
            $(this).data('clicked', true);
            var process = function() {
                if ($(this).data('clicked')) {
                   // Do your stuff
                    setTimeout(process, 100);
                }
            };
            process();
        },
        mouseup: function () {
            $(this).data('clicked', false);
        }
    });
```

Comment: thanks. I updated a jsFiddle using your method. (posted by another person here)  There seems to be a issue? http://jsfiddle.net/kacjd8dc/1/

Answer (score 0):

As an option you can set the handler for `mousemove` in `mousedown` and remove in `mouseup` as in code

```
function movehandler(e) {
    var pCords = e.pageY + e.pageY;
    var max = $('#md').height();
    var dg = 20 * (pCords / max);
    $('#md').css({
        'transform': 'rotate(' + dg + 'deg) '
    });
}
$('#md').mousedown(function (e) {
    $('body').on('mousemove', movehandler);
});
$('#md').mouseup(function (e) {
    $('body').off('mousemove');
});
$('body').mouseleave(function (e) {
    $('body').off('mousemove');
});
```

<kbd>[Jsfiffle](http://jsfiddle.net/kacjd8dc/3/)</kbd> Example is not ideally written but you can get the idea

EDIT: Note that `$('body').on('mousemove',` might not be sufficient dependent on your markup.

Comment: the issue is that the mousedown stop responding when the mouse is away from the red squire even though the mouse is still down. I'm looking for a way to keep the function running once the mouse is pressed and stop only after it's released.

Comment: But you agree running `mousedown` handler doesn't solve the problem, right? ;)

Comment: [This](http://jsfiddle.net/kacjd8dc/3/) is a bit updated, Mind that body in case of jsfiffle is an iframe. In general this task can't be solved without knowing your layout. And it is a different question. You can do research on your own, there are lots of examples on SO how to handle mousemove