# I want onmousedown behaves like onkeydown to maintain the call function

Tags: onmousedown

I create a simple function which continues to increment the global variable "i" when you maintain a key pressed down. Here the source code, very simple :

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">

var i = 0;

document.body.onkeydown = function()
{
    i++;
 console.log(i);    
};

</script>   

</body>
</html>
```

Now, I want the same effect when I replace onkeydown by onmousedown :

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">

var i = 0;

document.body.onmousedown = function()
{
    i++;

    console.log(i); 
};

</script>   

</body>
</html>
```

=> But it doesn't work because the console displays one time the i value.

Have you an idea ? Thank you in advance.

Comment: everything ok, which browser you use ?

Comment: potential duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4961072/jquery-continuous-mousedown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this doesn't work as you think it should is because the onkeydown event is kind of weird in that it's not 'just' on key**down**, but also at intervals afterwards.

Onmousedown however is only on the mouse**down** so to simulate the same behaviour you would have to do something like

```
<script>
var i=0;
var dt=100;
var interval;
document.body.onmousedown = function(){
    interval = setInterval(function(){i++;console.log(i);},dt)
}
document.body.onmouseup = function(){
    clearInterval(interval);
}
</script>
```

where dt is the time in ms between adding a value to i.

Comment: Wow, thank you very much ! You solved my problem because it's what I wanted. Thank you again.