# jQuery: change the value of input range continuously with mousedown event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to change the value of input range continuously with until mousedown on a button

code i tried 
HTML

```
<input type="range" id="points" value="50" min="10" max="100" step="1" />
<input type="button" id="plus" value="+" />
<input type="button" id="minus" value="-" />
```

jQuery

```
$('#plus').on('mousedown', function() {
  oldvalue = parseInt($('#points').val());
  $('#points').val(oldvalue + 5).change();
  console.log($('#points').val());
  });

$('#minus').on('mousedown', function() {
  oldvalue = parseInt($('#points').val());
  $('#points').val(oldvalue -  5).change();
  console.log($('#points').val());
  });
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3x6hykp5/)

with this code value of input range is changed only once, but my requirement is keep changing  the  value untill mousedown

Thanks in advance for help

Comment: So if I understand correctly, you want to dynamically change the max input range on `<input type="range" id="points" value="50" min="10" max="100" step="1" />`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4961072/jquery-continuous-mousedown

Comment: TBH it's not 100% clear - the question and the code contradict each other.   Do you mean: When you click on `#plus`, the range keeps going up until you click on `#minus` at which point it keeps going down until you click on `#plus`?   Or do you mean:  When you hold the mouse down on `#plus` it goes up and when you hold the mouse down on '#minus' it goes down?  The second seems more likely.

Comment: Did you see my working response posted 2 hours ago? :D

Answer (score 1):

You need to program the repeated nature, so you can use a setInterval() to do that like

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function setRepeatedMouseDown(el, callback) {
    var timer;

    $(el).on('mousedown', function() {
      callback();
      timer = setInterval(callback, 500);
    }).on('mouseleave mouseup', function() {
      clearInterval(timer);
    });

  }

  setRepeatedMouseDown('#plus', function() {
    $('#points').val(function(i, val) {
      return +val + 5;
    }).change();
  });
  setRepeatedMouseDown('#minus', function() {
    $('#points').val(function(i, val) {
      return +val - 5;
    }).change();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="range" id="points" value="50" min="10" max="100" step="1" />
<input type="button" id="plus" value="+" />
<input type="button" id="minus" value="-" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that event is triggered just once... what you should do is to be sure that (until event continues) your code is periodically executed.
So an idea can be to start a periodic timer on "mousedown" event using [setTinterval()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) function, and stop it on "mouseup" event with a [clearInterval()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_clearinterval.asp).
In my example I decleared an `interval` "global" variable.
I also executed the function just one time before setting the interval, otherwhise on click it doesn't be executed.

Hope it helps.

```
var interval;

$('#plus').on('mousedown', function() {
    startTime(true); // to work on click also
  interval =  setInterval(function(){startTime(true);}, 500);
});

$('#minus').on('mousedown', function() {
    startTime(false); // to work on click also
  interval =  setInterval(function(){startTime(false);}, 500);
});

$('.rangeMover').on('mouseup', function() {
  clearInterval(interval);
});

function startTime(plus) {
    var oldvalue = parseInt($('#points').val());
    if (plus) {
        $('#points').val(oldvalue + 5).change();
    } else {
        $('#points').val(oldvalue -  5).change();
    }
      console.log($('#points').val());
}

<input type="range" id="points" value="50" min="10" max="100" step="1" />
<input type="button" id="plus" class="rangeMover" value="+" />
<input type="button" id="minus" class="rangeMover" value="-" />
```

Be aware of HTML modification too.

PS: http://jsfiddle.net/uu9o1vam/ if you prefer.