# Move sprite onClick until its clicked

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I want to get effect :
Click on button and player is moving until i realese click

At that moment the code is working like :
I click button and the sprite (player) is moving.
But the problem is that the player is moving one time and i need to click again.

My Code for moving left/right

```
clickMoveLeft: function()
{
    if(!this.clickMoveLeft.clicked)
    {
        this.player.body.velocity.x += -160;
    }
},

clickMoveRight: function()
{
    if(!this.clickMoveRight.clicked)
    {
        this.player.body.velocity.x += 160;
    }
},
```

Creating/adding sprite:

```
    this.buttonleft = this.game.add.sprite(0, 600, 'button1');

    this.buttonleft.inputEnabled = true;
    this.buttonleft.events.onInputDown.add(this.clickMoveLeft, this);
    this.buttonleft.clicked = false;

    this.buttonright = this.game.add.sprite(320, 600, 'button1');

    this.buttonright.inputEnabled = true;
    this.buttonright.events.onInputDown.add(this.clickMoveRight, this);
    this.buttonright.clicked = false;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to set a boolean to `true` when `mousedown` fires, and then `false` when `mouseup` fires.  Then, while the boolean is `true`, have your movement called.

[Example from another question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4961072/jquery-continuous-mousedown)

Edit: Since you're using Phaser, you want [`mouseDownCallback`](http://phaser.io/docs/2.4.2/Phaser.Mouse.html#mouseDownCallback) and [`mouseUpCallback`](http://phaser.io/docs/2.4.2/Phaser.Mouse.html#mouseUpCallback), but it's the same concept.